# How does mad cow disease evade immune system?

Tags: immunology, prion

The mad cow disease is caused by prions right?

So how do prions avoid white blood cells and antibodies?

Comment: where have you looked for answers on this question? there is a lot of information that is easily accessible on the net.

Comment: Your question is a bit broad. There are many review articles written on prion infection and transmission. You can have a look at those and narrow down your question a little.

Answer (score 4):

Prions are proteins that we produced but that are misfolded and affect the folding of other proteins. As we produce these proteins, we don't recognize them as antigens. If we were to recognize our own proteins as antigens, then the immune system would constantly be fighting against ourselves. This is what is called a [autoimmune disease](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoimmune_disease).

While this was a simple explanation, the reality on how the immune system interact with prions might be a little more complicated. [Bradford and Mabbot (2012)](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3528271/) might be a good place to start for further learning

Comment: Oh wait, i didn't mean how it avoids antigens. i meant how it avoids antibodies :P lol srry

Comment: I did not even notice the typo. It is fine, just edit your post to fix it.

Comment: thx :) but does antibodies and white blood cells ignore them in the same way?

Comment: antibodies are created kinda randomly and are retained only if they fail to match molecules from the body. Given that prions are produced by the body, any antibody that recognize the prion as an antigen will not be retained. (note btw, I am not an immunologist)

Comment: If you think I answered your question, then you can click on the checkmark. You might eventually want to wait for more answers and more peer-reviewing though.